# Testing older anti-scald valve for correct function?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, water

Would it be acceptable to do the following:

1)  Turn on water at shower valve. Set temp at > 100F.
2)  Turn off (or drastically lower) cold water upstream.
3)  Measure Temp of water < 120F.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why not. Better safe than sorry. Can you get new parts if it's broken though or even a cartridge insert, might be the real question.

Comment: It takes a Moen 1225/1200 cartridge.  There were no brand markings on the outside of the valve, but the cartridge was marked Moen.  It is a late 80s Moen Standard valve w/o pressure balancing (i.e Moentrol, PoseTemp).  Using the above test-protocol produced no scald condition.  However, since this is a remodel and the wall is already open, will replace.  Excellent quality on almost 30 year old valve from Moen.

Comment: Fantastic! I'd 2nd that, probably all brass & no plastic with just some O-rings, Cups or washers to ever replace...I'd use it for as long as you can. I hate Moen nowadays, absolute garbage, & this is from when they were actually good. Plus, the escutcheon plate should allow for easy future cartridge replacement anyway.